# pandas and numpy - ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas df like this.

```
         up_value        valsup
0     59044.21272   59044.21272
1     59040.68568   59158.53136
2     59044.21272   59279.91816
3     59040.69570   59394.23280
4     59044.22274   59515.63370
...           ...           ...
6081  58917.07896  774036.35472
6082  58917.07896  774153.95368
6083  58917.08898  774271.68432
6084  58917.07896  774389.15160
6085  58917.08898  774506.88228
```

I'm trying to use numpy argwhere and create a new pandas column like this.

```
df["idx_up"] = np.argwhere(df["valsup"].values > df["up_value"].values)
```

But it returns the following error.

```
ValueError: Length of values (6085) does not match length of index (6086)
```

When I do, `print(np.argwhere(df["valsup"].values > df["up_value"].values))`, the output looks like this.

```
[[   1]
 [   2]
 [   3]
 ...
 [6083]
 [6084]
 [6085]]
```

So it seems like `np.argwhere` only returns 6085 values instead of 6086.

I wanna assign the output to pandas. Can someone tell me how to fix the error?

Thanks

Comment: What value do you want to assign? **True** and **False**?

Comment: @Lazyer This is what I wanna do. `idx_up = np.argwhere(df["valsup"].values > df["up_value"].values)` and then `idx_up = idx_up[0][0] if len(idx_up) else -1`. I need to assign the latter part to the datafarme

Comment: Then, **idx_up** column means **index if valsup>up_value else -1** ?

Comment: @Lazyer I'm trying to replicate this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72337982/18201044

Comment: @Lazyer Brilliant. That's what I wanted. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the code from one of the answers at that url,

```py
idx_up = idx_up[0][0] if len(idx_up) else -1
```

this code checks only idx_up at index 0.

You should add column first like

```
df['idx_up'] = -1
```

and update like

```
df['idx_up'].iloc[[x[0] for x in idx_up]] = [x[0] for x in idx_up]
```